How to identify devices connected via rear flex io port in system using wmi?
I'm working in c# application in which I want to display rear flex io port and devices connected to it.I'm using wmi queries to fetch details. From SMBIOS, I could only get the type of flex port connected to the system. USB type ports and its connected devices can be easily identified from the location property which starts with Port#. 
But for NIC type, could not differentiate whether they are connected through internal NIC or system PCIe slots or via rear flex port. I tried using AssocClass in Win32_PNPEntity class. But it is not working. Provides relation only if USB type is connected. Similar case for display port as well.  Can this be achieved using wmi classes. or Any 3rd party API to be used?

For monitor info I've been using Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\wmi -Class WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams -ComputerName $thisName.  Then sending the results down a pipe and using $_.InstanceName -match '(?i)^(?<InstancePath>DISPLAY\\(?<DisplayType>.*)\\[^\\_]+)_.*$' to break out the HKLM registry path 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY\' + $Matches.DisplayType + '\' + $Matches.InstancePath which I use to get the EDID.
